# How to receive KeyDown events in winforms

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to receive `KeyDown` events when a specific keyboard key is pressed to drive an arduino based rc vehicle using a winforms application. The vehicle is supposed to move when I press specific buttons on keyboard such as W,A,S,D but I am unable to do so and am looking for some advice.

I have tried driving the vehicle by pressing a `Button` control in and it worked fine but its difficult to control by clicking on buttons so I thought of using keyboard keys for driving it but I am unable to do so. the code I am using is attached.

```
  private void connect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
        comPort = new SerialPort();
        comPort.PortName = "COM3";
        comPort.BaudRate = 9600;
        comPort.DataBits = 8;
        comPort.StopBits = StopBits.One;
        comPort.Parity = Parity.None;
        comPort.Open();
        textBox1.Text = "Connected";
    }

    private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode.ToString() == "W")
        {
            pictureBox1.Visible = true;
            if (!forward)
            {
                forward = true;
                comPort.WriteLine("F");

            }
        }
        else if (e.KeyCode.ToString() == "S")
        {
            pictureBox2.Visible = true;
            if (!backward)
            {
                backward = true;
                comPort.WriteLine("B");

            }
        }
        ...
    }
```

I expect that when I press a key on the keyboard, an image box with an arrow image should appear on screen and the vehicle should move, but it doesn't happens.

Comment: Visual Studio is an editor, by putting it in your title and tags it suggests you are writing add-ins to visual studio.

Comment: Does your Form have the Focus (= where key-events go) ?

Comment: You don't need multithreading to create a responsive application. You *can't* use multiple threads to handle keyboard events or update the UI anyway

Comment: @HenkHolterman , sir when the key is pressed it is supposed to show an image box on the app and the command such as "F,S,B" is sent to the comport where the Xbee is connected and it forwards the command to arduino on remote end.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Sorry sir as i am not a professional programmer its just my first try making an application using c#, visual studio. Can you kindly suggest some tutorials so that i can somehow make it work. Any advice is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the `KeyPreview` property of the form to true. You can do this with the designer or by code:

```
this.KeyPreview = true;
```

Explanation: `KeyPreview` indicats if the form will receive key events before the event is passed to the control that has focus ([source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.keypreview?view=netframework-4.8)).

**Note:** If you press a keyboard key when a control has focus (e.g. a `TextBox`), the key press will be sent to the form (if `KeyPreview` is set to true) **and** to the control. If you want to prevent the control from receiving the key press, you can set `e.SuppressKeyPress` to true in the `KeyDown` event:

```
private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much Sir, your advice has just solved the issue.
Stay blessed.